# LeapMotion, Qt and signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, leap-motion

I'm working with a `Leap` and `Qt` on `Mac OS X` and I'm trying to emit a signal when the fingers position changed.

I'm (trying) to do this with `QObject` using :

```
class SampleListener : public Leap, public QObject{ 
     Q_Object

     class def }
```

but there is a problem with `moc_SampleListener` after compilation :

```
moc_SampleListener.cpp:94:18: error: no member named 'staticMetaObject' in 'Leap::Listener'
    { &Listener::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_PhLeap.data,
       ~~~~~~~~~~^
moc_SampleListener.cpp:111:22: error: no member named 'qt_metacast' in 'Leap::Listener'
    return Listener::qt_metacast(_clname);
           ~~~~~~~~~~^
moc_SampleListener.cpp:116:21: error: no member named 'qt_metacall' in 'Leap::Listener'
    _id = Listener::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
          ~~~~~~~~~~^
```

So I've **2** questions :

1. Am I trying to emit signals the wrong way?
2. Am I doing it the right way but with dummies errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Q_OBJECT` macro

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT

> The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class
>   definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other
>   services provided by Qt's meta-object system.

Oh, also, QObject [must be the first inherited class](http://slopjong.de/2008/10/07/staticmetaobject-is-not-a-member/)

Comment: I should have mention that it's already in the class, I'll edit my post